# Phaser - How to change the sprite image of a group?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser io

I'm making a simple game where the player has to avoid falling enemies (objects). The enemies are created like this:

```
    const enemies = this.physics.add.group();
    function enemyGen(){
      const xCoord = Math.random()*gameState.w;
      enemies.create(xCoord, 10, 'enemy').setScale(0.4);
    }
    const enemyGenLoop = this.time.addEvent({
      callback: enemyGen,
      delay: 800,
      callbackScope: this,
      loop: true
    })
```

I know that you can change the sprite image using:

```
player.setTexture('image');
```

So I tried this:

```
enemies.setTexture('image');
```

But this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through each item in the group and set the texture on the individual item.

```
enemies.children.iterate((child) => {
  child.setTexture('image');
});
```